# data_length and index_length do not changed for innodb

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have an InnoDB table. The version of mysql is '5.1.66-0+squeeze1'.
I want to see the size of table.

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE "tablename"
```

I obtain:

```
'tablename', 'InnoDB', '10', 'Compact', '27', '606', '16384', '0', '49152', '4194304', '55', '2013-07-26 15:53:04', NULL, NULL, 'utf8_general_ci', NULL, '', ''
```

I add one row and obtain:

```
'tablename', 'InnoDB', '10', 'Compact', '28', '585', '16384', '0', '49152', '4194304', '56', '2013-07-26 15:53:04', NULL, NULL, 'utf8_general_ci', NULL, '', ''
```

Why `data_length` and `index_length` were not changed?

Answer (score 0):

Both these variables are just estimates. The cost of maintaining an exact number, to the byte, of your data length and index length is prohibitive, since with a concurrently accessed server this would have to mean serializing writes.

InnoDB is a highly concurrent engine; it therefore chose the path of rough estimates.

How rough? Very rough. A 50%-200% "mistake" is quite common; I've seen more.